# 3rd REST connection failed

Tags: apache, http, mobile, flutter

I have a weird problem that I face when trying to consume a REST api that is located at my server.
the 1st and 2nd connection can be executed successfully, however, when I try to make the third one it hangs!
The problem occurs only when I try to connect from any mobile device (android or iOS using flutter or xamarin .... etc) 
and only when using my wifi network (It works fine when using my cellular data!)
while I have no problems when I use postman or using ajax request from any web page.
Here are my end point and I hope someone could help me to figure out and determine the exact cause:
https://camtend.com/api/v1/test_api1

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void login() {
    ar url = "https://camtend.com/api/v1/test_api1";
    var client = new http.Client();

    client
        .post(
        url,
    )
    .then((response) {
        print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");


        print("Response body: ${response.body}");
    }).catchError((e) {
   print('******* Error $e');
  }).whenComplete(client.close);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The URL returns 405 not allowed.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer - Did you use POST or other method?

Comment: Sorry, no, I used get.